# CodeIgniter Update function not working?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to update a database and change all the rows at once, this is the model I am using:

```
function amend_job($title,$description,$location,$date,$time,$pay,$jobcat,$job_id) //This function amends a job.//
{ 
    $amendJob=array(
    "JobTitle"=>$title,
    "JobDescription"=>$description,
    "JobLocation"=>$location,
    "JobDate"=>$date,
    "JobStartTime" =>$time, 
    "JobPay"=>$pay, 
    "JobCategory"=>$jobcat
    ); 

    $this->db->where('JobID', $job_id);
    return $this->db->update('HM_Jobs', $amendJob);
}
```

The code runs with no database or syntax errors, I think the update syntax may be wrong, any suggestions?

I have updated the function above, here is the controller function:

```
function amend_job()
    { 
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Title','required|trim|max_length[50]|xss_clean|strip_tags'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','required|trim|max_length[200]|xss_clean|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('location','Location','required|trim|max_length[50]|xss_clean|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('date','Start Date','required|trim|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('time','Time','required|trim|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pay','Pay Rate','required|trim|max_length[10]|xss_clean|number');        
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('jobcat','Job Category','required|trim|max_length[30]|xss_clean');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
                $data['usertype'] = $session_data['usertype'];
                $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
                $this->load->view('amend_job_view', $data);
                return false;
            }

            else{
                //Sending form input.//
                $title=$this->input->post('title'); 
                $description=$this->input->post('description'); 
                $location=$this->input->post('location'); 
                $date=$this->input->post('date');
                $time=$this->input->post('time'); 
                $pay=$this->input->post('pay');             
                $jobcat=$this->input->post('jobcat');

                //Sending session data.//
                $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
                $data['usertype'] = $session_data['usertype'];
                $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
                $job_id=$this->uri->segment(3);

                $this->load->model("job_model"); 

                    if($this->job_model->amend_job($title,$description,$location,$date,$time,$pay,$jobcat,$job_id))
                        { 
                                echo $this->db->last_query();
                            /*Start of the PHP generated JavaScript that shows the details the user registered with.
                            echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
                            echo "alert('That job has been successfully amended, returning to your home.');\n";
                            echo " window.location.href='(my link)'; </script>";
                            End of the PHP generated JavaScript that shows the details the user registered with.*/
                        }
                    else
                        { 
                            $data['msg']="An error was encountered when trying to add this job."; 
                        }
                }
        $this->load->view("customer_view",$data); 
    }
```

Now the $job_id is not being found and the query is:

```
UPDATE `HM_Jobs` SET `JobTitle` = 'dfsdsf', `JobDescription` = 'fd', `JobLocation` = 'fds', `JobDate` = '2014-01-01', `JobStartTime` = '02:00:00', `JobPay` = '32.00', `JobCategory` = 'Carpentry/Woodwork' WHERE `JobID` = 0
```

I am using the uri segment and the link is as follows:
(my site)/HandyMan/index.php/job_controller/amend_page/43

Comment: try to echo the query using echo $this->db->last_query(); and execute it and check whether you are getting any errors

Comment: The query is echoed as I expected it to: UPDATE `HM_Jobs` SET `JobTitle` = 'Tree removal', `JobDescription` = 'Tree and stump need removing from my garden, it', `JobLocation` = 'Bradford, BF1', `JobDate` = '2014-07-23', `JobStartTime` = '13:00:00', `JobPay` = '7.25', `JobCategory` = 'Carpentry/Woodwork' WHERE `JobID` = '34'

Comment: did you executed it in database..if not execute and check whether it is throwing any error or not..

Comment: There are no db errors however it is not updating because it is updating where JobID = $job_id and it is echoing $job_id as 0

Comment: check whether from controller you are getting value for $job_id and also in model

Comment: so your problem is uri segment. because if you uri segment dont work then it gives 0 default value.

Comment: did you load url helper in autoload.php file

Answer (score 1):

you are getting two ids in functions one is `$job_id` and `$id`. and you are not using `$id` anywhere. I think you should check again the parameters and check again calling function. may be you are mixing these two $ids.

Answer (score -2):

You have an extra comma in the array

```
$amendJob=array(
    "JobTitle"=>$title,
    "JobDescription"=>$description,
    "JobLocation"=>$location,
    "JobDate"=>$date,
    "JobStartTime" =>$time, 
    "JobPay"=>$pay, 
    "JobCategory"=>$jobcat, 
                          ^
    );
```

Remove it and change array to

```
$amendJob=array(
    "JobTitle"=>$title,
    "JobDescription"=>$description,
    "JobLocation"=>$location,
    "JobDate"=>$date,
    "JobStartTime" =>$time, 
    "JobPay"=>$pay, 
    "JobCategory"=>$jobcat
    );
```

and also make sure that the keys in the array `$amendJob` are the field names of table.

Comment: That extra comment is valid. I don't like it, but it's valid